# Multiple "container" class on a single page

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

In Bootstrap3, we can further divide a column into multiple columns by inserting a row. e.g

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-md-6></div>
                 <div class="col-md-6></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6"> </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My question is, do we need to have the nested *row* to be wrapped in a *container* class, becuase documentation says, *container* contains the *rows*. I also want to know whether having more than one *container* class on a page is fine and syntactically correct? If yes, what will be the difference in above example if I include the nested *row* in a *container*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> do we need to have the nested row to be wrapped in a container class

No.

> also want to know whether having more than one container class on a page is fine and syntactically correct?

Yes, although you cannot nest containers.

> If yes, what will be the difference in above example if I include the nested row in a container.

That would involve nesting containers, which as I said above is invalid.

Sidenote: [Bootlint](https://github.com/twbs/bootlint) can point out most container-related usage errors.